# How to get true or false if a number is hexadecimal or not?

Tags: javascript

I want a method which if given a hexadecimal number (e.g. `0x01`) returns `true`. I tried with a string argument, but I need number type check! For example:

```
isHex(0x0d) //-> true
isHex(12)   //-> false
```

Comment: There is no "hexa number" type in Javascript. `0x...` is merely different **syntax** to express a number. The result is still a pure numeric value, no different than when you type it in as decimal number.

Comment: You can only distinguish whether _string representations_ of numbers are hex or decimal according to the language rules. Once parsed, a number is a number regardless of how it was originally represented and you cannot reverse that.

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant Java instead of Javascript? http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Hexadecimalintegerliteral.htm

Comment: @The_Grits - The same comments apply if it's Java.

Comment: Why would you want to have a method for that? Aren't you the programmer knowing which of the two you typed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible as hexadecimal number literals are just another way of representing the same number (translated during parsing) and there’s no way to differentiate them:

```
0x10            //=> 16
0x10.toString() //=> '16'
typeof 0x10     //=> 'number'
typeof 16       //=> 'number'
```

This would only be possible if you passed the literal as a string:

```
function isHex(num) {
  return Boolean(num.match(/^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i))
}

isHex('0x1a') //=> true
isHex('16')   //=> false
```

Comment: thanks :) this is not possible.. i need to find another way..!

Comment: let num = 0x10; isHex(num.toString()); // works for me

Comment: @NoxFly No, it doesn’t (I get `false`) as `(0x10).toString()` is `'16'`.

Comment: @DavidJeong this is sounding like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. You are trying to accomplish something (which you haven't mentioned) and you've decided the way to do it has something to do with detecting the format in which a number was specified, so you asked about _that_. Maybe if you can express _what it is_ that you are **actually** trying to accomplish someone could provide more help.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript cannot tell you how a value of any type was achieved. Much like you can't reach from `12` back to `6+6` or `3*4`. `0x0d` and `12` are the exact same value.

Answer (score 3):

The option to type numbers in hexadecimal or octal notation besides decimal notation is merely a *syntax* affordance. You're not creating any sort of different numerical value. `0x0D` (hexadecimal) is exactly the same numerical value as `13` (decimal) is exactly the same as `015` (octal). Merely their notation differs by their [radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix). It is sometimes convenient to work with numbers in different radices, it doesn't change the actual number.

Long story short: you can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Your number literal  is parsed to a number value before being passed to the function. The function only receives the a 64-bit number value which represents e.g. 13, but it can't know whether you wrote `13`, `13.0`, `0b1101`, `0xd` or `0o15`, or even more complex expressions like `26 / 2` or `10+3`.

This kind of information is not exposed in JavaScript. The only way you might manage to do it would be getting the source code of your script, and using your own JS parser.

Alternatively, consider passing a string instead.

Answer (score 1):

^([0-9A-Fa-f])+$

is the unique pattern that is working for me

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps but I use logic like below to block dodgy domain scripts from loading in a browser, such as this URL:

```
https://0e29fa5ee4.09b074f4cf.com/165575ce5432f25ac96b16e917b1750c.js
```

The logic used once components have been extracted from the URL is basically...

```
var S='0e29fa5ee4';

var IsHex=parseInt(S,16).toString(16)===S.toLowerCase();
```

NB: Of course you may also lose some valid domains such as "abba" so a little more logic may be needed.